# Word VB Header Text Box Editing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to edit the text in an object contained in the header of Word document but I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm able to change the text of the header but not the text in the text box in the header. I'm looking at using a text box (or any object) that is specific to that page and isn't duplicated on every page. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to reference the correct Header in VBA?

Comment: Please also specifiy *what kind of text box*. Word has many things called "text box" and the way to address them with code is different in each case. If you don't know what kind, describe the command used to create it.

Comment: bibadia - not sure what you mean by the correct header.  I'm able to change the text in a header but not an object.

Comment: Cindy - I guess it really isn't just a text box I'd like to modify but I'd like to know how to change the text in any object that might be in the header.

Comment: Do you know how to change "an object" in the body of a document? Can you explain what you use for that? Basically, the approach is the same, but we have to understand what you already know and what it is you're actually asking about - and that's really not very clear at all...